# How to call a module from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that returns the title of a youtube video when provided its id and it works fine the issue is when I call the module from within a function it replies undefined whereas when I call outside a function it works fine and prints the title. Why is it not working Inside a function and how can I make it work? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
//Works 
const line = "zPfvActHhTQ"
getYoutubeTitle(line, function(err, title) {
  console.log(title)
})


//Doesn't work
function tester() {
  const line = "zPfvActHhTQ"
  getYoutubeTitle(line, function(err, title) {
    console.log(title)
  })
}
tester()
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not interpreting the return value of the function? This will be `undefined` as you return nothing. In the console, the return value of a function is also printed. The rest should then also print like outside of the function scope.

Comment: I'm logging the variable result on the console why do I need to return anything?@ssc-hrep3

Comment: ok i have to be *that guy* and say that the problem could not be in what you're showing us.. it's either in the code around the area or in the module itself ;-;

Comment: That is all the code. That's why I asked the question, if a module can in fact be called inside a function then the problem Is from the module itself. @TheBombSquad

Comment: it could be that it is actually calling the function before it is doing the work inside of it. NodeJs is weird that way. I'm not sure how to fix it at this moment, but I put it out there just incase someone may know how